# Colocar ID dentro de um TITLE

Tags: html

Estou precisando colocar uma id em um title exemplo

```
<div title="<span id=""></span>"> </div>
```

Mas não obtive resultado, a alguma forma de eu fazer essa função?

Comment: Qual é a sua intenção em colocar uma tag dentro de um atributo de outra tag ?

Comment: Estou com uma função .load, que quando clico em uma certa div ele coloca novos dados dentro do title

Comment: No caso, quando você clicar em uma div "x" ele atualizará o titulo da div com alguma informação é isso?:

Comment: Isso mesmo clicou em uma div X ele atualiza o title da div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

você pode usar o `attr()` para acessar o atributo title e colocar o novo valor, e depos utiliza-lo para pegar novamente, exemplo:

```js
$("div").click(function() {
  $("div").attr('title', 'Meu Título'); // coloca a informação na div
  alert($("div").attr('title')); // recupera o valor

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div title="">Clique na DIV</div>
```

Comment: depois que você fizer o load do arquivo html essa html passará a ser parte do seu html atual,  então você procura onde esta o texto que você quer e encontra um seletor que possa pegar o valor desse texto.

Comment: Aqui um exemplo, na função animaLoad eu chamo um load para carregar um arquivo externo de texto que possui um titulo  e quando ele é carregado eu dou um alert: http://jsfiddle.net/x8e6mpks/2/

Answer (score 0):

Não é possível colocar um `id` ou `class` dentro de um `title`, ou mesmo HTML. O atributo `title=""` serve apenas para [especificar informação adicional](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_title.asp)  a um elemento.

No entanto se a tua intenção é de personalizar o atributo `title`, podes fazê-lo da seguinte maneira:

```css
#meuTitulo {position: relative;}

#meuTitulo[title]:hover:after {
  content: attr(title);
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 100%;
  padding: 4px 8px;
  z-index: 20;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background-color:royalblue;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" id="meuTitulo" title="Olá, eu sou um link!">StackOverflow</a>
```